# Check if userform is shown

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, userform

Let's see...I'm working with macros in Excel, so I have a Macros called "Save" that is activated by a button and this macro works with a specific form: "frm_income", I create a new form: "frm_Expenses" and I want to use  the same macro so, my question is how I code the conditional if the frm_Expenses is shown or activated and use the macro.

Here is part of the macro

```
Sub Save()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Final As Integer
frm_Expenses.btn_Save.Enabled = True
frm_Expenses.btn_Erase.Enabled = True
For i = 4 To 1000
  If Sheet5.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
  Final = i
  Exit For
  End If
  Next
 sheet5.Cells(Final, 2) = frm_Expenses.txt_Code
```

....
And maybe I was thinking something like this

```
Sub Save()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Final As Integer

if frm_Sales.(something..activate...shown..) then

frm_sale.btn_Save.Enabled = True
frm_sale.btn_Erase.Enabled = True
For i = 4 To 1000
  If Sheet5.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
  Final = i
  Exit For
  End If
  Next
 sheet5.Cells(Final, 2) = frm_Sales.txt_Code
else
frm_Expenses.btn_Save.Enabled = True
frm_Expenses.btn_Erase.Enabled = True
```

Comment: how do you show your userforms?

Comment: You could check the `Visible` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Sub Save(frm As Object)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Final As Integer
    frm.btn_Save.Enabled = True
    frm.btn_Erase.Enabled = True
      For i = 4 To 1000
          If Sheet5.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
              Final = i
              Exit For
          End If
      Next
      sheet5.Cells(Final, 2) = frm.txt_Code
      ....
```

Then call from your form:

```
Save Me
```